# Attempting to Speed up my Web App using Flash, Javascript, JSP

Tags: web-applications, optimization

I am currently working on a web application using Flash, Javascript and using a JSP (running on Apache Tomcat).  I am trying to speed it up.

The application is embedded into another page using an `<iframe>`.  Often we will embed the applicaiton many times into one page.

The page in the iframe is a JSP with some Javascript and a Flash SWF.  The basic structure is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script1.js"/>
        ... 
        <script src="script8.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object>
            <param ... />
            <param ... />
            <param ... />
            <embed src="myFlash.swf" ...>
            </embed>
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

After doing some informal testing I have found that for each application that is added to a page the page takes an additional four seconds to load.  This is a linear increse in time which makes sence to me.

```
LoadingTime = (4 seconds)*NumberApplications + (3 seconds)
```

I think that these are the candidates for slowness:

- Javascript
- Flash
- Server Side Processing
- Download Time

#### Javascript

I have used Firebug to profile the Javascript but no function is taking large percentage of the time and the overall time seems very small.  Here are the approximate results:

- Function A takes up 25% of the time.  Its time (including nested calls) is 1.5 seconds*.  This seems almost neglegable.
- Function B, C, D, E Take up less than 10%
- There are many other functions that take up less than 2% of the total time

It looks like the JS is fast and not the cause of the app being slow.

* *This time is for when there are 21 apps on the page and the total loading time is 85 seconds*

#### Flash

I don't know how to profile the Flash code.  I see a grey loading bar for some of the SWFs (some of them skip the grey scroll bar).  I think that profiling this is my next step.

#### Download

Looking at the Net tab in Firebug it looks like there are a couple of things that are a bit slow on the download.  Each JSP has about 8 javascript files associated with it.  Downloading the first one is always a little bit slow (takes about a full second).  I am not sure why this is.  I am wondering if it is because there are not enough connections supported by my Tomcat server.

Other questions that come to mind are:

- It is making requests for the same 8 js files for each jsp would it be possible to put the js files on the main page so they are only requested once.
- Should I increse the number of connections to Tomcat?
- Since I am loading many applications I would like `app1` to begin initializing itself after it has downloaded (and not wait for `app2` to finish downloading).  How can I see when `app1` has begun running, relitive to the downloads

#### Server Side Processing

I think that any Server side processing should be reflected by the download time.  For example if one of the JSPs is taking a long time it would be easy to see since the JSP will take a long time to download.

#### Question

- What is the standard way to figure out what the slow part of the web app is?
- What is the easiest part to speed up?
- I know have some idea about how long some things are taking (download and JS) but I don't know how these two relate to each other.  When does the JS start executing?  When the download is finished or when it is finished for that file?
- Are there other things other that could be making my applicaiton slow?

Comment: Regarding the js files: browsers have a maximum number of parallel open connections at a time. This means you should have as few js files as possible. My suggestion is to concatenate the files into a big one, minify it, enable gzip compression and make sure you set the correct cache headers. Since you are using apache for the server side you might want to consider [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) - a tool that does all the things I mentioned. It's easy to use and I've had a great experience using it at work

Comment: @Dan, I just put all of the JS files into one file.  I did not zip it but this did not have any effect.  I don't think it is worth the effort to zip it since it is not taking a significant amount of time to download and it is cached so in theory the user should only have to download it once.

Comment: Well, than this might not be a js problem. You could try to move the script tag at the bottom of the page, so it doesn't freeze the rendering and it looks more fluid, but I don't think that will help much either. You could get a more accurate js profile by adding `console.profile()` at the top of the js file and `console.profileEnd()` at the bottom. But I think the problem is elsewhere (maybe flash, but most likely on the serverside)

Comment: Consider using some caching mechanism on the server. I suspect there might be a lot of things in common between the iframes, and you might save some time by caching it on the session.